# On a sequence of integers

Tags: diophantine-approximation

I recall a well-known theorem due to Minkowski.

**Theorem.** If $\theta$ is irrational and $\alpha$ is not of the form $\alpha = m\theta+n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$, then there are infinitely many integers $q$ such that $|q| \|q\theta +\alpha \|<1/4$.

Here $\|x\|$ denotes the distance of $x$ from $\mathbb{Z}$.

My question is: are there choices of $\theta$ and $\alpha$ such that the infinitely many integers $q$ can be characterized precisely? In some numerical tests I have discovered that $q$ describes important sequences, recognised by The On-Line Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: It might help to add links to some of those sequences. Is it clear that more than just the first few numbers agree?

Comment: If $\theta=1/\sqrt{5}$, I get the first terms of https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C19%2C341%2C6119%2C109801%2C1970299&language=english&go=Search
But another known sequence appears if $\theta=1/\sqrt{3}$.